Constructing a function $z=f(x,y)$ with certain properties
I have been trying to construct a function $f:[-1,1]\times [-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, preferably smooth and simple function such that

$f(x,y)$ is large if both $x,y$ are small ($x,y\approx -1$),

$f(x,y)$ is large if $x$ is large and $y$ is about $0$,

$f(x,y)$ decreases gradually everywhere else.


So the contour looks something like

I want to construct such a function and ideally given by elementary functions (polynomials/ exponentials/ trig functions, etc) but I have no idea how to even begin. I know that many such functions exist and so the question is not really well defined, but any such function with roughly the above growth rate will do, thank you so much in advance.

@Yves Daoust, the domain for $y$ is $[-1,1]$, so when $y$ is about zero, it is not considered small but "medium size", I should have made that clearer, thank you.

@Yves Daoust $-1<0$.

@Yves Daoust How does the figure not match?

@YvesDaoust It does not have to have a local minima... it only has to possess the the 2 local maximums described above and the decay property in 3... Please point out exactly what the problem is or stop saying something is wrong when you can't point it out.

@YvesDaoust such (smooth) function certainly exists and the surface is diffeomorphic to the plane $[-1,1]^2$. But how to construct one is another question altogether.

One idea would be
$$
f(x,y) = C_1 e^{-A_1 ((x+1)^2+(y+1)^2)} + C_2 e^{-A_2 ((x-1)^2+y^2)}
,
$$
where you can play around with the coefficients until you get something you like.
For example, with $C_1=C_2=1$ and $A_1=A_2=2$, you get this:
Wolfram Alpha link.

Thank you so much! How did you begin to approach these kind of questions? The functions looks simple enough but I wouldn't have thought of constructing such function to begin with.

The graph of a Gaussian $e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$ is like a round hill where the surrounding quickly becomes very nearly flat. If you change $x$ to $x-a$ and $y$ to $y-b$, it will be centered around the point $(a,b)$ instead of $(0,0)$. And if you add two Gaussians at different locations, you get two hills – in this case at $(-1,-1)$ and $(1,0)$. With the extra parameters, you can vary their height and steepness.
